# Why is the JavaScript Fetch API called an API?

Tags: javascript

Why is fetch called an API? Is it safe to say "axios API" like people say "fetch API"? I know they are both libraries, but I have no idea why one is referred to as an API and the other is not.

Comment: Where do you see that 'fetch is called an API'? What 'fetch' are you talking about?

Comment: Fetch is a [standard](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/) that exposes some APIs - the fact that it's called "the fetch API" is just popular terminology but isn't official in any way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api

Comment: API = *"Application programming interface"* ... why wouldn't it be considered one?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  how about the Promise API?

Comment: @PeterB Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` are both `APIs` of the browser to handle `ajax` calls. `axios` is a wrapper around the `XMLHttpRequest` `api`.

Comment: Is an API wrapper not another API?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion API is a very generic term which refers to the exposed parts of a software package, generally destined to use by other developers.

That includes the public/exported classes, methods, objects, whatever provided by a library that you can use in your own code (excluding private/scope-protected parts that you shouldn't be able to manipulate).
For example, Oracle call Java's public classes its API : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

But it can as well be a set of interfaces that you can call to interact with the software, e.g. an HTTP REST endpoint that will accept requests to change the software's behaviour.
For instance, Microsoft provides a REST Management API for its Azure services : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest

I expect both librairies you mention to have an API, which is the part you will be using in your code.

A library could be considered to have no API if it worked by changing the behavior of an existing API, although it would be fair to consider the modified interfaces part of the library's API. E.g. a library overwriting `XmlHttpRequest.prototype.send` to log all requests could either be considered to have no API or to have an API containing `XmlHttpRequest.prototype.send`. It would probably have another item in its API making it possible to define the log location anyway.

Comment: Just like we have the promise API?

Comment: I don't know where the promise spec is nowadays, but when I checked it out a few years ago there was a specification, which was a document for implementers (google, mozilla, etc.) that described what should be done to have a standard Promise concept implemented ; it included an API but no implementation, telling implementers what tools they should provide to developers so they could work in the same way whatever implementation they used.